# Will this circuit work for wiring a 3.8v screen into my car's power?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, diodes, dc-dc-converter, automotive

I'm trying to wire a 3.8V screen, 3.8V battery, and my car's 5V power source together and ensure that the device will be powered by the 5V power source when it's available and that the battery is charged at the same time, and then when that power source goes away the device will run off of the battery without losing power.

Will the following circuit accomplish this?

1. Positive lead of the 5-volt power source to the anode of the 1N5817 diode(breakdown voltage of 8V).
2. Negative lead of the 5-volt power source to the cathode of the 1N5817 diode.
3. Positive lead of the battery to the cathode of the 1N5817 diode.
4. Negative lead of the battery to the common terminal of the 10uF capacitor.
5. The other end of the terminal of the 10uF capacitor to the screen.

Comment: Schematics are much better than words. There's a CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and it's very easy to use. Double-click a component to edit its properties. R, H and V for rotate, horizontal and vertical mirrors. Hit **Save and Insert** when finished. No CircuitLab account required.

Comment: Please draw a schematic. Based on what you wrote, you already shorted the 5V supply with a diode. Also batteries are not charged by putting 5V into them. 3.8V sounds like a lithium battery. If you connect a lithium battery to 5V without a charger, you will get a damaged battery at best, or fireworks and explosion at worst. Do not play with lithium batteries unless you know enough about them to feel confident you will not cause them to explode or catch fire.

Comment: Are you familiar with what nasty things you will see in an automotive electrical system. These can be supply voltage upto 24V, reverse battery at that voltage, transients some several 100 volts depending on the source. Take a look at this application note by ST. https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2689-protection-of-automotive-electronics-from-electrical-hazards-guidelines-for-design-and-component-selection-stmicroelectronics.pdf You may not see any of this but it is very possible. As noted previously without an annotated schematic we are at a loss to help you.

Answer (score 2):

First - I'd recommend you draw a schematic of this instead of describing it in words.

Based on your text, you're planning on shorting the diode with the +5V.

You list this as a 3.8V battery.  Is this a rechargeable Lithium battery? If so, then you need to use a battery charger IC for safety. LiIon batteries are very touchy if they aren't charged properly and can blow/burn up.

Comment: Please don't ask questions or further info in the space reserved for answers. These should be comments.